# What will happen if I sign in user using phone number without user creation in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

So, I am trying to create a sign-in and sign-up flow using firebase with primary requirement using phone number.

But I found that I am only able to sing up the user using `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` only.
Now the issue is how do I sign up the user using phone number.

If not then how does firebase sign in user using phone number?

Comment: What platform is your application on?

Comment: its an app... btw flutter but
consider it like android/ios

Answer (score 0):

A Firebase Authentication user account is created when signing up/in with phone number when you [call the `signInWithCredential` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#sign-in-the-user). At that point you can get the `FirebaseUser` object, and the UID from that.

The relevant code from the documentation:

```
mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
     .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");

                FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                // ...
```