# Signing up users using phone number react-native-firebase

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

I am working on an application that will sign up users based on their phone numbers. Everywhere I have read, there are articles regarding signing in users using their phone number. While researching for this I landed on a stackoverflow article itself that mentioned that the signInWithPhoneNumber() article will work for sign up when queried for first time, and will be used for sign in once the user is created as in this article [What will happen if I sign in user using phone number without user creation in firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59590056/what-will-happen-if-i-sign-in-user-using-phone-number-without-user-creation-in-f).
Going by this article, I wrote the following code to achieve my purpose

```js
import auth from "@react-native-firebase/auth";
console.log("going to sign up with", numberToSend);
// numberToSned is the input number to which the message has to be sent
const confirmation = await auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(numberToSend);
```

I also set up a dummy number to test the feature.
But whenever this request is made my application shuts down by itself

Also I do not get any error on the console regarding this
[image]

So I wanted to ask is their a way to sign up users using their phone number in firebase with react-native?

Answer (score 0):

As the link you describe (but didn't share) says: Firebase makes no distinction between signing **up** with a phone number or signing **in** with a phone number. The code for both cases is exactly the same, as shown in the documentation on [Firebase phone authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth).

Comment: I have shared the article and you were the one who commented on it. But I had one confusion. https://rnfirebase.io/auth/phone-auth In this article it talks only about signing in the user. Also for signup it says that you can create user using email, then you can later on add the phone number. So I am a bit confused if it is possible since I am using their method to connect to firebase API and not directly. Maybe that method only supports signing in.

Comment: RNFirebase is a wrapper around the Firebase SDKs, so it works in the same way with just a different API and on a different platform. If you find their documentation unclear, there is an edit link right at the top of each page where you can suggest improvements. If your app crashes, find the error message and stack trace in its logcat or other output, and add those to your question.